# Parallel execution of JMeter Loop Controller iterations

Tags: parallel-processing, jmeter

In my JMeter test I have, as part of the setup phase, a Loop Controller that calls a REST endpoint n times (n is defined in a single line csv file).
The result of a Counter is used in the call to the endpoint.
This setup phase takes a long time to execute, does anyone know if it is possible to execute the loop iterations in parallel? 
I have looked at https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-parallel-controller-in-jmeter/ but that doesn't seem to provide a solution for parallel execution within a Loop Controller

Answer (score 0):

If you need parallel execution - you need to add more threads.

1. Given you're in a "setup phase" it would be logically compliant to use [setUp Thread Group for this](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-setup-thread-group-jmeter-when-preparing-load-test/)
2. Now you need to define dynamic number of threads according to you `n`, given `n.` resides in `n.csv`  which lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation you can read its value using [__FileToString() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) as `${__FileToString(n.csv,,)}`

   [image]
3. Now you can add a [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) as a child of the thread group - it will be executed by as many parallel threads as you set it up in the `n.csv` file

   [image]

Comment: I'm trying your approach but I run into several issues: 
1) for the HTTP request I need a counter, the Counter Controller doesn't seem to work (always has value 1)  
2) before the HTTP request is executed, several JDBC requests need to run only once, but they run for every thread even though I put them in Once Only Controllers  
3) my Test Plan contains multiple tests, each in it's own Thread Group. The setup is different for each test.  
Do you think these issues are solvable with this approach?